# Using the union function to generate new columns

Tags: sql, oracle, report

So far I've been self-taught when it comes to anything sql, the problem with teaching yourself is that while you can often hack a fix, it might not be the best practice in accomplishing your goal.  The following code is one of these hacks:

```
select breed, sum(mar_11) as mar_11, sum(apr_11) as apr_11
from (
  select d.breed, d.qty as mar_11, 0 as apr_11
  from dogs d
  where d.entry_date between '01-MAR-11' and '31-MAR-11'
  union all
  select d.breed, 0 as mar_11, d.qty as apr_11
  from dogs d
  where d.entry_date between '01-APR-11' and '30-APR-11'
) t
group by breed;
```

The accomplished goal of the above code is to provide a formatted report that shows total dogs born in both March and April.  This is great when we're dealing with a few time periods but when you move into 20-30 different time periods the code gets tedious and repetitive.

The second hack I have devised is to make the report be dynamic and show the previous six months without having to recode each month.  I have accomplished this with a bash script and GNU Date which pass the variables through the command prompt.

```
(e.g.)
sqlplus64 ilove/dogs@dogville @myreport var1 var2 var3 var4
```

My questions are as follows:

1) What tool can I use to be more efficient in my sql statements (i.e. less repeating the same code over and over with changing the dates)?

2) Is what I'm trying to achieve even considered good practice (or should I do post processing lets say via a pivot table)?

3) How can I make my sql statements dynamic without the need of bash and GNU Date?

Comment: I would try and use a PIVOT table if at all possible. They are powerful, but not the simplest to learn. Also if you need to have a variable amount of columns, then you will have to use dynamic SQL to create the PIVOT, adding to the complexity!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select
  breed,
  SUM(CASE WHEN entry_date BETWEEN '01-Mar-11' AND '31-Mar-11' THEN qty ELSE 0 END) AS mar_11,
  SUM(CASE WHEN entry_date BETWEEN '01-APR-11' AND '30-APR-11' THEN qty ELSE 0 END) AS apr_11
FROM
  dogs
WHERE
  entry_date BETWEEN '01-Mar-11' AND '30-Apr-11'
GROUP BY
  breed
```

**EDIT:** This month and previous 5 months

```
select
  breed,
  SUM(CASE WHEN entry_date >= ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'MM'), -5)
            AND entry_date <  ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'MM'), -4)
           THEN qty ELSE 0 END)                                      AS month_1,
  SUM(CASE WHEN entry_date >= ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'MM'), -4)
            AND entry_date <  ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'MM'), -3)
           THEN qty ELSE 0 END)                                      AS month_2,
  SUM(CASE WHEN entry_date >= ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'MM'), -3)
            AND entry_date <  ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'MM'), -2)
           THEN qty ELSE 0 END)                                      AS month_3,
  SUM(CASE WHEN entry_date >= ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'MM'), -2)
            AND entry_date <  ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'MM'), -1)
           THEN qty ELSE 0 END)                                      AS month_4,
  SUM(CASE WHEN entry_date >= ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'MM'), -1)
            AND entry_date <  ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'MM'),  0)
           THEN qty ELSE 0 END)                                      AS month_5,
  SUM(CASE WHEN entry_date >= ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'MM'),  0)
            AND entry_date <  ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'MM'),  1)
           THEN qty ELSE 0 END)                                      AS month_6
FROM
  dogs
WHERE
      entry_date >= ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'MM'), -5)
  AND entry_date <  ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'MM'),  1)
GROUP BY
  breed
```

Comment: While I haven't used the case function yet, this is the solution that was hoping for.  Cuts back on a lot of the repetition and gets to the point.  Any thoughts on how to make the date range always six month prior?

Comment: Thanks guys, this will be something very helpful to add to my repertoire.

Answer (score 2):

As a minor (if not frivolous) addition to @Dems six-month-span query (too big for a comment), since you're using SQL*Plus you can use its [`new_value`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_twelve013.htm#sthref1336) clause and  [substitution variables](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_five.htm#sthref453) to set the column headings to match the month.

Using the same `add_months(trunc(sysdate, 'MM'), n)` method you can generate text labels matching each of the last six months. You can use whatever format you want, I've gone for `'Mon RR'` to be close to your original hard-coded column names. Each of the generated values is aliased as `x_month_1` etc.; the `column ... new_value ...` clause makes that availble later in the script as a substitution variable which you can reference as `&y_month_1`.

```
column x_month_1 new_value y_month_1;
column x_month_2 new_value y_month_2;
column x_month_3 new_value y_month_3;
column x_month_4 new_value y_month_4;
column x_month_5 new_value y_month_5;
column x_month_6 new_value y_month_6;

set termout off

select to_char(add_months(trunc(sysdate, 'MM'), -5), 'Mon RR') as x_month_1,
       to_char(add_months(trunc(sysdate, 'MM'), -4), 'Mon RR') as x_month_2,
       to_char(add_months(trunc(sysdate, 'MM'), -3), 'Mon RR') as x_month_3,
       to_char(add_months(trunc(sysdate, 'MM'), -2), 'Mon RR') as x_month_4,
       to_char(add_months(trunc(sysdate, 'MM'), -1), 'Mon RR') as x_month_5,
       to_char(trunc(sysdate, 'MM'), 'Mon RR') as x_month_6
from dual;

set termout on
set verify off
```

The `termout off`/`on` stops this appearing in the output, and the `verify off` stops it telling you when it uses a substitution variable.

Then just change the `AS` alias clauses in Dem's query; instead of `AS month_1` use `AS "&y_month_1"`. The double-quotes are needed because I chose a date format with a space in it; this stops it causing an error.

Or if you prefer to keep the presentation an the query separate, leave the aliases and use another `column` clause to achieve this instead:

```
column month_6 heading "&y_month_6"
```

Either way you'd get something like:

```
BREED          Mar 12     Apr 12     May 12     Jun 12     Jul 12     Aug 12
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
Beagle              1          4          0          0          0          0
...
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a group by to group dogs into months and years:

```
SELECT 
    breed, EXTRACT(MONTH FROM entry_date) AS month, EXTRACT(YEAR FROM entry_date) AS year, sum(qty) AS number_of_dogs
FROM
    dogs
GROUP BY 
    breed, EXTRACT(MONTH FROM entry_date), EXTRACT(YEAR FROM entry_date)
```

Then you can add logic to filter results to a certain time frame. For instance:

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT 
        breed, EXTRACT(MONTH FROM entry_date) AS month, EXTRACT(YEAR FROM entry_date) AS year, sum(qty) AS number_of_dogs
    FROM
        dogs
    GROUP BY 
        breed, EXTRACT(MONTH FROM entry_date), EXTRACT(YEAR FROM entry_date)
)
WHERE
    year = 2012 AND month < 8
```

Would get you number of dogs born this year in the months jan-july

Comment: `COUNT(entry_date)` needs to be `SUM(qty)`.  Also, this the needs pivotting to get the layout the OP desires.  *(Personally I agree that the normalised set is better practice, but the OP asked for a flat file style.)*

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, Dems!

Comment: If we're looking at a table with 1mil+ rows, would this query be optimized?  I might not be correct in this but wouldn't it group all dogs in the table before selecting just the dates needed?

Comment: You could filter the dates in an inner select and group after if you'd prefer (in other words flip the second query in the post inside out), but a million rows isn't that big and grouping is a pretty quick process.

Answer (score 1):

I think does what you want:

```
select to_char(d.entry_date, 'YYYY-MM') as yyyymm, breed,
       sum(d_qty)
from dogs d
group by to_char(d.entry_date, 'YYYY-MM'), breed
order by 1, 2
```

This creates a separate row for each month and breed.  If you need to get these in one row, then you want the PIVOT syntax, or do the pivot in Excel.

It is quite possible that pivoting in Excel is sufficient.  You can also pivot by being explicit (as I think other responders have suggested):

```
select breed,
       sum(case when to_char(d.entry_date, 'YYYY-MM') = '2012-06' then d_qty end) as qty_201206,
       sum(case when to_char(d.entry_date, 'YYYY-MM') = '2012-05' then d_qty end) as qty_201205,
       ...
from dogs d
group by breed
order by 1
```

Comment: Stuck on 9i so no way to pivot (that I know of) inside of the DB and my goal is zero touches after the query is run so I can set up a cron job and be done.

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle, there's an idiom commonly used to pivot like this, usually involving `SUM(DECODE(...)))` or `SUM(CASE WHEN...THEN...)`.

```
select breed
,      sum(decode(TO_CHAR(entry_date,'YYYYMM'),'201103',qty,0) mar_11
,      sum(decode(TO_CHAR(entry_date,'YYYYMM'),'201104',qty,0) apr_11
from dogs d
group by breed;
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: The DECODE function in Oracle should if deprecated (if it is not).  You should answer with CASE rather than DECODE.

Comment: This was right in front of my face and I didn't see it.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at `PIVOT`

http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/PIVOT

Also `EXTRACT` or `TO_CHAR` to filter your dates

Comment: How great would that function be, unfortunately I'm stuck with 9i.